# what regex would help capture line matching with a string and also deleting every line after it?

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

Lets say for example I need to strip this note.

What's Changed

Bug Fixes

yolo-123

Other Changes

234

45

I want to delete the line 'other Changes' and every line after it. Any easy regex i can use?

Comment: What tool are you using here?

Comment: im using powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `[\w\W\n\r]+(?=Other Changes)` will do it

[image]